# Error "found unhashable key" while trying to read a yaml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, yaml

I am trying to read .yaml file but getting "found unhashable key" error. Sample code and .yaml is mentioned below for reference

test.py

```
file_path = "test.yaml"
try:
    with open(file_path) as file:
        res = yaml.safe_load(file)
except Exception as e:
    print("e",e)
```

test.yaml

```
jobs:
- job: CLEANUP
  connection:
    dbms: mysql
    user: {{username}}
```

Comment: If you're running into this problem with helm templates, consider just [excluding these files](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks/issues/420).

Answer (score 5):

Quote your value,

from `{{username}}` to `"{{username}}"`

Comment: Cant change the .yaml file

Comment: Otherwise you have to do some string parsing based on the input format to get it done

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it because of {{username}}?
All built-in immutable types are hashable, but mutable ones are not, so hashable types include all numbers, strings (both unicode and bytes) and tuple. Common unhashable types include list, dict and set, and {{username}} is dict syntax.